# AngularJS UI Router: redirect to other state isn't working (net::ERR_FAILED)

Tags: angularjs, redirect, angular-ui-router

I am building an application using `AngularJS` and `UI-Router` for routing. Basically, users need to log in and based on the logic, the site will redirect users to different views.

My situation:

After `username` and `password` are provided, I am trying to redirect to another state in my login controller. However, I always receive an `net::ERR_FAILED` message.

I have tried `$state.go()` and `$location.path()`, but neither is working.

My question:

How should I set up the configuration to make it work?

Code in App.js

```
    'use strict';

/**
 * @ngdoc overview
 * @name clientApp
 * @description
 * # clientApp
 *
 * Main module of the application.
 */
angular
  .module('clientApp', [
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngCookies',
    'ngResource',
    'ngRoute',
    'ngSanitize',
    'ngTouch',
    'toaster',
    'ngFileUpload',
    'ui.router',
    'ui.bootstrap'
  ])
  .config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
    function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

      $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

      $stateProvider.state('site', {
        'abstract': true,
        views: {
          'navi@': {
            templateUrl: "views/navigation.html",
            controller: 'NavigationCtrl',
            controllerAs: 'navigation'
          }
        },
        resolve: {
          authorize: ['authorization',
            function(authorization) {
              return authorization.authorize();
            }
          ]
        }
      }).state('home', {
        parent: 'site',
        url: '/',
        data: {
          roles: []
        },
        views: {
          'content@': {
            templateUrl: "views/main.html",
            controller: 'MainCtrl',
            controllerAs: 'main'
          }
        }
      }).state('register', {
        parent: 'site',
        url: '/register',
        data: {
          roles: []
        },
        views: {
          'content@': {
            templateUrl: 'views/register.html',
            controller: 'RegisterCtrl',
            controllerAs: 'register'
          }
        }
      }).state('login', {
        parent: 'site',
        url: '/login',
        data: {
          roles: []
        },
        views: {
          'content@': {
            templateUrl: 'views/login.html',
            controller: 'LoginCtrl',
            controllerAs: 'vm'
          }
        }
      }).state('about', {
          parent: 'site',
          url: '/about',
          data: {
            roles: []
          },
          views: {
            'content@': {
              templateUrl: 'views/about.html',
              controller: 'AboutCtrl',
              controllerAs: 'about'
            }
          }
        }).state('products', {
        parent: 'site',
        url: '/products',
        data: {
          roles: []
        },
        views: {
          'content@': {
            templateUrl: 'views/products.html',
            controller: 'ProductsCtrl',
            controllerAs: 'products'
          }
        }
        }).
        state('product', {
          parent: 'site',
          url: '/product/:productCode',
          data: {
            roles: []
          },
          views: {
            'content@': {
              templateUrl: 'views/product.html',
              controller: 'ProductCtrl',
              controllerAs: 'product'
            }
          }
        }).state('cart', {
        parent: 'site',
        url: '/cart',
        data: {
          roles: []
        },
        views: {
          'content@': {
            templateUrl: 'views/cart.html',
            controller: 'CartCtrl',
            controllerAs: 'cart'
          }
        }
      }).state('productCockpit', {
          parent: 'site',
          url: '/productCockpit',
          data: {
            roles: ['Admin']
          },
          views: {
            'content@': {
              templateUrl: 'views/productcockpit.html',
              controller: 'ProductcockpitCtrl',
              controllerAs: 'productCockpit'
            }
          }
        }).state('manageProduct', {
          parent: 'site',
          url: '/productCockpit/:productCode',
          data: {
            roles: ['Admin']
          },
          views: {
            'content@': {
              templateUrl: 'views/manageproduct.html',
              controller: 'ManageproductCtrl',
              controllerAs: 'manageProduct'
            }
          }
        }).state('userCockpit', {
          parent: 'site',
          url: '/userCockpit',
          data: {
            roles: ['Admin']
          },
          views: {
            'content@': {
              templateUrl: 'views/usercockpit.html',
              controller: 'UsercockpitCtrl',
              controllerAs: 'userCockpit'
            }
          }
        }).state('manageUser', {
          parent: 'site',
          url: '/userCockpit/:username',
          data: {
            roles: ['Admin']
          },
          views: {
            'content@': {
              templateUrl: 'views/manageuser.html',
              controller: 'ManageuserCtrl',
              controllerAs: 'manageUser'
            }
          }
        }).state('accessdenied', {
          parent: 'site',
          url: '/denied',
          data: {
            roles: []
          },
          views: {
            'content@': {
              templateUrl: 'views/denied.html'
            }
          }
      });
    }
  ]);


angular.module("clientApp")
  .run(['$rootScope', '$state', '$stateParams', 'authorization', 'principal',
    function($rootScope, $state, $stateParams, authorization, principal) {
      $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toStateParams) {
        $rootScope.toState = toState;
        $rootScope.toStateParams = toStateParams;

        if (principal.isIdentityResolved()){
          authorization.authorize();
        }
      });
    }
  ]);
```

Code in Login Controller:

```
'use strict';

/**
 * @ngdoc function
 * @name clientApp.controller:LoginCtrl
 * @description
 * # LoginCtrl
 * Controller of the clientApp
 */
angular.module('clientApp')
  .controller('LoginCtrl', function ($state, AuthenticationService) {

    var vm = this;

    function login() {
      vm.dataLoading = true;
      AuthenticationService.Login(vm.username, vm.password, function (response) {
        if (response.success) {
          AuthenticationService.SetCredentials(response.token);
          $state.go('products');

        } else {
          AuthenticationService.ClearCredentials();
          ///FlashService.Error(response.message);
          vm.dataLoading = false;
        }
      });
    }

    vm.login = login;


  });
```

Html View:

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
  <h2>Login</h2>
  <div ng-show="vm.error" class="alert alert-danger">{{vm.error}}</div>
  <form name="form" ng-submit="vm.login()" role="form">
    <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': form.username.$dirty && form.username.$error.required }">
      <label for="username">Username</label>
      <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.username" required />
      <span ng-show="form.username.$dirty && form.username.$error.required" class="help-block">Username is required</span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': form.password.$dirty && form.password.$error.required }">
      <label for="password">Password</label>
      <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.password" required />
      <span ng-show="form.password.$dirty && form.password.$error.required" class="help-block">Password is required</span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-actions">
      <button type="submit" ng-disabled="form.$invalid || vm.dataLoading" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
      <img ng-if="vm.dataLoading" src="data:image/gif;base64,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" />
      <a href="#/register" class="btn btn-link">Register</a>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide related `html` code as well? And how do you do the redirect? By click a button or ?

Comment: I added the html view. I used the ng-submit directive to call the login method in my controller.

Comment: It might be a problem comes from backend service. How do you implement `AuthenticationService`?

Comment: Hi all, thank you for your answers. I finally found the problem. It was my backend service which was not working correctly. Thank you for your help!